# TypeError: $(...).live is not a function

Tags: live, jquery

I have a problem with jquery 1.9.1 . I have searched it but these are not solved my problem.

```
    $('.sm2_expander').live('click', function() {
    $(this).parent().parent().toggleClass('sm2_liOpen').toggleClass('sm2_liClosed');
    return false;
});
```

Everybody said that "use 'on' function" but this time my code never work.

```
$(document).on("click", "a.offsite", function(){ alert("Goodbye!"); });
```

Edit : Here is my using prject page : [draggable link](http://boagworld.com/demos/sitemap/)

Comment: The `on` version of `$(".sm2_expander").live("click",func)` is `$(document).on("click",".sm2_expander",func)`. Don't know where you got `"a.offsite"`.

Comment: can you share the html also

Comment: need more info. Probably use http://jsfiddle.net to explain the problem.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In your example you have used the selector `a.offsite` but there are no elements matching this selector in your page. That might be the reason why it is not working.

```
$(function(){
    $(document).on('click', '.sm2_expander', function(){
        alert('bye');
        $(this).parent().parent().toggleClass('sm2_liOpen').toggleClass('sm2_liClosed');
    })
})
```

I think you can shorten this to

```
$(function(){
    $(document).on('click', '.sm2_expander', function(){
        $(this).closest('li').toggleClass('sm2_liOpen sm2_liClosed');
    })
})
```

Comment: Thank you. That is my solution.

Answer (score 9):

.live() was introduced in jQuery 1.3, therefore it won't work with earlier versions.

**.live() has also since been deprecated in jQuery 1.7 onwards.**

**The alternatives are .on() and .delegate()**

See related question jQuery 1.9 .live() is not a function on how to migrate existing code.

I used "jquery-1.8.3.min.js" and my problem solved.

Answer (score 6):

**Try this out :-** http://jsfiddle.net/trdb9/

JS:-

```
$(document).on("click", "a.offsite", function () {
    alert("Goodbye!");
});
```

HTML:-

```
<a class="offsite">Click Me</a>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response but it doesn't work. Example page is : boagworld.com/demos/sitemap

Comment: Your demo site is using jQuery 1.3 version

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `jquery-migrate-1.1.1.min.js` or higher. I guess there are big changes coming in `jquery`, one being making everyone who relied on `.live` to find new ways.

Anyhow, try that and it should work.

Answer (score 2):

Try replacing `live` with `on` in your code.

```
 $('.sm2_expander').on('click', function() {
    $(this).parent().parent().toggleClass('sm2_liOpen').toggleClass('sm2_liClosed');
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your response but it doesn't work. Example page is : http://boagworld.com/demos/sitemap/

Answer (score 0):

If you have a live site, I will recommend to use jQuery Migrate

https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/

It will automatically add the deprecated but needed functions.